# metrics for my api powered by jersey

Tags: jersey, metrics

I try to instrumente my Jersey webservice with Metrics

http://metrics.codahale.com/manual/jersey/

I don't understand how to use this library?
Do I need to add something in my web.xml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To instrument your Jersey web service, you must add the [metrics-jersey](http://metrics.codahale.com/manual/jersey/) module to your application, it contains a @Provider implementation class (make sure Jersey find it) that allow you to instrument your Jersey resources methods annotated with @Timed, Metered and ExceptionMetered.

By default, Metrics reports through JMX, so you can use JConsole to validate your instrumentations.
Like Alex wrote, there are others reporting options but it requires additional configuration or code (call `enable` method on the Reporter).
For example you can fetch reports in [JSON by HTTP](http://metrics.codahale.com/getting-started/#reporting-via-http), or have you webservice send reports to a monitoring server such as Graphite.

Comment: What is the @Provider implementation and how do we hook it in?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you just need to include `metrics` lib to the build path. On web-services methods you just use annotation @Timed.

To see the reports, you must enable the reporting style you like - [reporters](http://metrics.codahale.com/manual/core/#reporters)

Comment: yep I think I understand the same thing but I don't see anything on the output...

Comment: Did you enable the console reporter?

Comment: Try console reporter in order to insure that the whole thing works.

Comment: with console reporter, I have an output in the log files of tomcat but no metrics just a line with ===== characters. I thnik I miss some web.xml configuration but not sure

Comment: Well, I can't provide you any pretty example at the nearest future. Matbe in some time.

Comment: ok it works but it was not easy

I had to add the package com.yammer.metrics.jersey for the init-param com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages in web.xml

then I added the servlet and I have a json output with the stats

yay!

Comment: well done! But nothing about that in manual on the officil site.

Comment: @Julien Would it be possible to show exactly what you added to the web.xml? I'm also trying to instrument Jersey with http://metrics.codahale.com

Answer (score 0):

Drop your linen and start your grin'n.  I got this working!

1. Hook up the servlet.  You need a generic spot to make and store the metrics.  Build one of these for both `MetricsRegistry` and `HealthCheckRegistry` :

   ```
   public class MetricsServletContextListener extends MetricsServlet.ContextListener {
       public static final MetricRegistry METRIC_REGISTRY = new MetricRegistry();

       @Override
       protected MetricRegistry getMetricRegistry() {
           return METRIC_REGISTRY;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Set the servlet context with the data in some startup area:

   ```
   sc.getServletContext().setAttribute(
       "com.codahale.metrics.servlets.HealthCheckServlet.registry", 
       healthChecks
   );
   sc.getServletContext().setAttribute(
       "com.codahale.metrics.servlets.MetricsServlet.registry", 
       MetricsServletContextListener.METRIC_REGISTRY
   );
   ```
3. Url is:  http://blah/blah/metrics/metrics?pretty=true
4. Create one of these guys.  This hooks up the metrics to Jersey:

   ```
    @Provider
    public class TmaticInstrumentedResourceMethodDispatchAdapterWrapper implements ResourceMethodDispatchAdapter {

        private InstrumentedResourceMethodDispatchAdapter adapter = null;

        public TmaticInstrumentedResourceMethodDispatchAdapterWrapper() {
            adapter = new InstrumentedResourceMethodDispatchAdapter(MetricsServletContextListener.METRIC_REGISTRY);
        }

        @Override
        public ResourceMethodDispatchProvider adapt(ResourceMethodDispatchProvider provider) {
            return adapter.adapt(provider);
        }
    }
   ```
5. Tell jersey about it.  Since it uses the @Provider annotation it must be in an area that can scan for it.  I had to add mine to the web.xml here but you might not have to:

   ```
   <init-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
       <param-value>blah.endpoint,blah.utils</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ```
6. And add the annotatation `@Timed` to your jersey endpoint.